# What is the bias (as a function of number of points) of the average of data as an estimator of the mean of the Weibull distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

The Weibull distribution's cumulative distribution function  is:

$
F=1-\exp\left[-(\frac{x}{b})^c\right]
$

By differentiating to obtain the pdf, and integrating it with respect to $x$ to obtain the first moment, i.e. the mean, we get ($\Gamma$ is the euler gamma function):

$
\mu=b\Gamma(1/c+1)
$

If we have n experimental data thought to be Weibull-distributed, we can calculate its average, i.e:

$
\bar x=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i
$

What is the bias of $\bar x$ with respect to $\mu$ as a function of $n$? I have found papers about the bias of estimators for the distribution parameters i.e. $b$ and $c$. I can also do Montecarlo with some reasonable values of $b$, $c$, and $m$ to get a feel, but I am wonder if there is a theoretical expression that is known, but that I am missing because maybe I am not searching for the right keywords. Anybody knows the answer or a paper that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ is an iid sample with $X_i \sim \operatorname{Weibull}(b, c)$ with parametrization $F_X(x) = 1 - \exp(-(x/b)^c)$, then as you have already calculated, $$\operatorname{E}[X_i] = \mu = b \Gamma(1/c + 1).$$  Therefore, by linearity of expectation, $$\operatorname{E}[\bar X] = \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{E}[X_i] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mu = \mu.$$  Therefore, the sample mean $\bar X$ is unbiased.

Comment: Thanks! Practically speaking though, it will be unbiased only until we collect some significant number of samples i.e. it will probably have some error with 5 points, which gets reduced if we collect 30 points, and converges to $\mu$ as we collect more.  Would you say the only way to get a feel for this "convergence" is numerically, or could there be a way to theoretically know this behavior as a function of $b$ and $c$ and $n$.

Comment: @RodrigoBernal Bias is a **systematic** tendency for an estimator to deviate away from the true mean, in the sense that the expected value of the estimator does not equal the true mean.  What the above proof shows is that there is no such tendency and that the sample size has nothing to do with it.  In other words, you are thinking about error but calling it bias.  Error (in particular, mean squared error) captures the degree of variability of an estimator from the true mean.